# Javascript runtime error on Vf page while using Blob(HTML)data as string

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html, contentversion

I have a VF page and I want to print it by using javascript code (window.print()) and the reason behind javascript - This page is getting used by other teams and I wanted to print this page only on certain conditions.

VF page code:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="crm_ConsoleDocumentPreviewController" id="ConsoleDocumentPreviewFrame" standardStylesheets="false" action="{!init}"><apex:includeLightning /><html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px !important;
            padding: 0px !important;
            background: transparent;
            height : 100%;
        }

    </style><apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.vlocity_cmt__vlocity_assets, '/css/vlocity.css')}"/>
    
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.vlocity_cmt__vlocity_core_assets, '/latest/vlocity_core_assets.js')}"></script>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.vlocity_cmt__angular_strap_bundle_1_6)}"></script>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.vlocity_cmt__cardframework_core_assets, '/latest/cardframework_assets.js')}"></script>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.vlocity_cmt__cardframework_core_assets, '/latest/cardframework.js')}"></script>
    <script src="{!$Resource.vlocity_cmt__SldsAngular}"></script>
</head><body>
 <apex:pageBlock id="pgblock" >

        <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg" ></apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:iframe src="data:{!DataEncoding},{!ContVersion}" width="100%" scrolling="true"  id="documentIframe" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('Before resize Function');
    var isPrint = "{!IsPrintVar}";
    if(isPrint != '' && isPrint != null && isPrint != undefined && isPrint == 'true'){
        window.print();    
    }
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    
        
    function onWindowResize() {
        // Getting JS error at below line.
        var datastring= "{!ContVersion}";
      
     if(datastring.length > 0){
          document.getElementById('documentIframe').height = (window.innerHeight - 22) + 'px';
      }else{
          document.getElementById('documentIframe').height = '0px';
      }
    }
    console.log('After resize Function');

 </script></html></apex:page>
```

---

Controller used by above VF page

Method of the controller which is causing issue:

```
public String getContVersion()
{
    String contentVersionString = '';
    switch on contVersion.FileType
    {
        when 'PDF'
        {
            contentVersionString = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(contVersion.VersionData);
        }
        when 'HTML'
        {
            contentVersionString =  contVersion.VersionData.toString();
        }
    }
    return contentVersionString;
}
```

If the file type is pdf it's working fine, but if the contentVersion file type is HTML, it is throwing run time error in javascript. Because of this JS error, I am not able to run print() function.
[image]

Please suggest, what should I try, tried some hacks and used List, also tried with some conversion, but I  might be trying in wrong direction. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is subject to an injection attack, because you're not properly escaping the HTML data. For some arbitrary data, this is at worst just an error, but a clever user could use this to cause all kinds of damage. The fix is simple; just escape your data:

```
var datastring= "{!JSENCODE(ContVersion)}";
```

You should always do this for any parameter that can't be pre-validated for correctness.

Comment: Thank you so much, this code works for HTML data type. Will this also work if the ContVersion type is "pdf"? Because this page is getting used for generating more contentDocuments. So, I  just want to get confirmation about the pdf version also?

Comment: @AaryaTiwary It will work for any type of string, with or without special characters.